# Convert from IEnumerable to ISet

Tags: c#, hashset

```
public override ISet<string> SetCellContents(string name)
{          
    HashSet<String> list = graph.GetDependents(name);
    return list;
}
```

`Graph.getDependents(name)` returns an `IEnumerable` of a `HashSet<String>`. I get an error:

> "cannot convert from IEnumerable to ISet"

I am not sure what to do?

Comment: Just to be sure `GetDependents` returns: `IEnumerable<HashSet<string>>`?

Comment: Do you mean `IEnumerable<HashSet<string>>` or that it returns an `IEnumerable<string>` which just so happens to already *be* a `HashSet<string>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should instantiate a new `HashSet` and pass it the `graph.GetDependents(name)` as input. In addition as `GetDependents` returns `IEnumerable<HashSet<string>>` then use `SelectMany` to flatten the inner collections before creating the new `HashSet`"

```
public override ISet<string> SetCellContents(string name)
{
    return new HashSet<string>(graph.GetDependents(name).SelectMany(hs => hs));
}
```

As a side note using the name `list` for something that is not a `List<T>` (or in general) is not a good practice. You could use something like `dependenciesSet` instead.